# How can I reduce the html5 audio buffer size?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm creating an audio element with javascript and I'd like to control either the buffer size or the amount of buffer fill before the audio starts playing so that there is less delay before the audio plays and less latency.

The audio data is a stream and the user will choose to play one stream out of many so it isn't feasible to 'preload' the audio data at all.

Comment: If you manage to cut down the buffer size, it might not be enough to play the entire audio clip and it might start buffering right in the middle. There's a reason why the buffer is there, and I assume the browsers do quite a good job guessing the size that's needed for it.

Comment: you could reduce the bitrate of the file (like 128kbps) so that the file is smaller, thus it downloads faster.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't seen any references to changing the buffer size. One suggestion would be to start the audio with the volume turned down. then stop and reset the to the start and volume back up. perhaps even setting the start point may cause internal code to load the buffer with data. i think you need to prime the buffer.